# How to extract first character from a string in Shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I have got a string (delimited by comma) from which I need to extract 'first character'

```
Eg  'A - one,B - two,C - three'
```

Expected output

```
A,B,C
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Are you asking for code without showing any research efforts?

Comment: Would you reckon that one would have asked a question without doing anything ?  I am not a new newbie to UNIX at the same time I am not a master though

Comment: Not meant to be disrespectful in anyway, but the community insists on posting research efforts before posting a question, not _blatantly_ asking for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'A - one,B - two,C - three' | awk -F ',' '{OFS = ","} {for(i=1;i<=NF; i++) {$i=substr($i,1,1) }; print $0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

For most cases, this should work (ascii)

```
echo 'A - one,B - two,C - three' | tr ',' '\n' | cut -b1
```

For character based selection (e.g. utf) this one is more suited

```
echo 'A - one,B - two,C - three' | tr ',' '\n' | cut -c1
```

Comment: This would not work if there was no space after the first character.

Comment: Should be fixed now

Comment: Better would be `cut -c1` since not all characters are 1 byte in length (for example UTF8).

Comment: .oOo. true, true .oOo.

Answer (score 0):

sed solution:

```
echo 'A - one,B - two,C - three' | sed 's/\(.\)[^,]*,\{0,1\}/\1,/g;s/,$//'
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you explain me the 'sed' expression

Comment: @SathishKumar of course. The dot in the parentheses is your first character `\(.\)`, then there is any amount of non-comma characters `[^,]*` and an optional comma `,\{0,1\}`, because there is not a comma after the last part. You substitute this every part with only the first char and a comma, so you have: first char comma first char comma and so on, and then you remove the last comma with the second substitution `s/,$//`. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

This **sed** one-liner should work for your example:

```
sed -r 's/\s-[^,]*//g
```

Test:

```
kent$  sed -r 's/\s-[^,]*//g'<<< 'A - one,B - two,C - three' 
A,B,C
```

If you love to solve it with **awk**:

```
awk -F'\\s*-[^,]*' -v OFS="" '{$1=$1}7'
```

will work:

```
kent$   awk -F'\\s*-[^,]*' -v OFS="" '{$1=$1}7' <<<'A - one,B - two,C - three' 
A,B,C
```

Comment: But he didn't say anything about if there always is whitespace and dash after the first character. If there wasn't, this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution in "pure" bash:

```
X='A - one,B - two,C - three'

IFS=',' read -ra A <<< "$X"
RES=''
for W in "${A[@]}" ; do
   RES+=",${W:0:1}"
done

echo ${RES:1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'A - one,B - two,C - three'| awk '{print $1substr($3,4)substr($5,4)}'

A,B,C
```